# How to debug (analyse) OOME in cascading

Tags: java, hadoop, memory, jvm, cascading

I have piece of code written in cascading that sometimes (randomly) produces `OutOfMemoryError`. It does not process a lot of data, so such behaviour (for me) is strange.

I would like to analyze memory usage of my cascading job in order to find leaks but unfortunately I do not know how to do it. In standard situation (standalone or webapp application) I could use some tools like YourKit, VisualVM, JPRofiler, JMap etc, but probably in profiling hadoop jobs those tools are useless.

How I can analyse Memory usage of hadoop jobs? How you are finding source of problems in such situations?

Comment: *"but probably in profiling hadoop jobs those tools are useless"* - have you tried?

Comment: @the8472 No, I didn't try but I think that It will be difficult if your code is running on (let's say) 30 nodes.

Comment: Having partial information may make it less useful, but does that automatically make it useless?

Comment: @the8472 Agreed, but still I believe that there are better ways